# Facebook multi-friend-selector + new javascript API = BROKEN?

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml, serverfbml

I am using the fb:serverfbml tag to render a multi-friend-selector inside an IFrame.

I am using the new javascript API. I have been trying ALL DAY to get it working.

When I click on the underlines 'selected' link (to filter by the selected friends) the whole page refreshes and the selected friends disappear.

Does the multi-friend-selector just not work with the javascript API?

```
<fb:serverfbml> 
    <script type="text/fbml"> 
        <fb:request-form action="http://apps.facebook.com/rollingrazor/" target="_top" method="POST" invite="true" type="Blah blah blah" 
        content="Blah blah! &lt;fb:req-choice url=&quot;http://apps.facebook.com/rollingrazor/&quot; label=&quot;Let me check my friends&quot; /&gt;">
            <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite your friends"  rows="5" cols="5"  bypass="cancel" target="_top"  /> 
        </fb:request-form>
    </script> 
</fb:serverfbml> 

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
   FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
   });
  };
  (function () {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  } ());
 </script>
```

Can someone give me a working example using new javascript API with a multi-friend-selector?

Comment: This works for a website normal? i mean, we are using opengraph and oauth, and we need invite friends, theres is still bug? in what link i can follow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get it working with the new JS API so I am using the old JS API for the multi friend selector and the new one for everything else.  It's annoying but according to their developer roadmap some new friend request features (hopefully an API call) will be released in June.  I plan on creating my own invite widget at that point.