# facebook error The page you requested was not found. - When inviting friends to join

Tags: facebook

I am a .net developer, using iframe xfbml and asp.net of course.

I am getting the following error:

The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.

```
* Return home
* Go back to the previous page
```

I am using the request-form tag as following:

```
       <fb:request-form target="_top" action="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp" 
            method="POST" invite="true" type="myappliation" 
            content="come see
            <fb:req-choice url='http://apps.facebook.com/myapp' label='i am coming' />  " > 
            <fb:multi-friend-selector rows="3" showborder="false" actiontext="its now shame to ask for help!" max="10"  style="height:100px;" target="_top" />  
       </fb:request-form>
```

This code is working for some of the users, but for new ones they recieve that error. Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem for a while. I tried with 2 applications, same configuration, with inviting the same user, and it's working for one of them but not the other...

By browsing similar post, I found no other solution except using the old API (see this post related) :

[Facebook multi-friend-selector + new javascript API = BROKEN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886826/facebook-multi-friend-selector-new-javascript-api-broken)

However, this does not help me since, I need the FB.ui function to pop up a dialog...

Facebook bugs me !